# Problems calling a stored procedure using Entity Framework: expects parameter not supplied

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATEA PROCEDURE USP_U_Pricing 
(  
@ProductId int 
)  
AS  
BEGIN
....
END
```

I setup the DbParameter like this:

```
var pProductId = dataProvider.GetParameter(); //This returns a DbParameter
pProductId.ParameterName = "@ProductId";
pProductId.Value = productId;
pProductId.DbType = DbType.Int32;
```

And call the procedure like This:

```
this.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>("USP_U_Pricing", parameters).ToList();
```

Where pricing is the SP name and parameters an array that contains only the pProduct object. It is there, I checked.

When this line is executed, I get the following exception:

> Procedure or function 'USP_U_Pricing' expects parameter '@ProductId', which was not supplied.

I've been reading around and testing different ways to set the parameter up, but no result.
If I set two parameters, one called ProductId and the other @ProductId, I get an error that the parameter name should be unique....

Can you help me please?

EDIT: parameters is an array that contains the parameter information. It is populated because I call a method with this signature:

```
 ExecuteStoredProcedureList<TEntity>(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
```

Passing the pProductId as parameter:

```
dbContext.ExecuteStoredProcedureList<PricingInfo>(
                "USP_U_Pricing",
                pProductId);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try with this.

```
this.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>("EXEC USP_U_Pricing @ProductId", pProductID);
```

By the way, in your code I can't see the creation of the 'parameters' argument passed to SqlQuery.

Comment: Worked, thanks :)
Btw, any idea why do I have to explicitly define the parameters if they already have a name in the DbParameter object?