# Trouble with OUTPUT parameter in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a strange stored procedure call using Entity Framework 6.1.3

```
 var p = _dataProvider.GetParameter(); 
        ...
 var pSeasonStageId = _dataProvider.GetParameter();
 pSeasonStageId.ParameterName = "SeasonStageId";
 pSeasonStageId.Value = seasonStageId;
 pSeasonStageId.DbType = DbType.Int32;

 var pTotalRecords = _dataProvider.GetParameter();
 pTotalRecords.ParameterName = "TotalRecords";
 pTotalRecords.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
 pTotalRecords.DbType = DbType.Int32;

 var playerStats = _dbContext.ExecuteStoredProcedureList<LeaguePlayerStatsModel>(
            "LeaguePlayerStats2",
            pCategoryId,
            pTeamId,
            pSeasonStageId,
            pFixtureId,
            pPlayerId,
            pCountApp,
            pOrderBy,
            pPageIndex,
            pPageSize,
            pTotalRecords);
```

And in the stored procedure `leagueplayerstats2`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LeaguePlayerStats2]
    @ShotsPerGame   bit = null,
    @Rating bit = null,
    @Assist bit = null,
    @Aggression bit = null,
    @Dribble bit =null,
    @CategoryId int =0,
    @TeamId int=0,
    @PlayerId int =0,
    @FixtureId int=0,
    @SeasonStageId int =0,
    @OrderBy int =0,  -- 0: rating, 1: goals/teamgoals
    @PassAcc bit =null,
    @PageIndex          int = 0, 
    @PageSize           int = 2147483644,
    @CountApp bit=0,
    @TotalRecords       int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
```

It always shows the message:

> The formal parameter "@SeasonStageId" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

though on debug the param `@Seasonstageid Direction = Input`.

Any ideas and thoughts are appreciated

Comment: I don't see the direction of `pSeasonStageId ` set anywhere in the code

Comment: Looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11820603/15498) I'd say you ought to be prefixing your parameter names with `@`s and also may need to provide an explicit parameter list in the string identifying the stored procedure to call. It's complaining about `@SeasonStageId` which is the tenth formal parameter to the stored procedure, and you're only supplying ten parameters in your call to `ExecuteStoredProcedureList` so I'd say its currently matching parameters by *position* rather than by *name*.

Comment: I thought that with pSeasonStageId.ParameterName = "SeasonStageId"; the storedproc would understand what param name it should look for, but in reality, it doesn't. Thanks for your help